# deploy java project to heroku with error code H14 "no web processes running"

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have originally a java project which is a single Clock GUI class with no other personal project on the build path.
I followed the guide step by step in the link
[How to convert existing Java Project to Maven in Eclipse?](https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/)
 with my pom.xml file pasted below:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ClockGUI</groupId>
  <artifactId>ClockGUI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ClockGUI</name>
  <description>this is used to try converting java to maven then to heroku</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then I followed the steps in the link:[Deploy the app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#deploy-the-app)
. My procfile is this:

```
web: java -jar target/ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I also added my procfile

into the root directory and pushed everything by running:

```
git push heroku master
```

Then I ran the command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

with the result saying:

```
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free
```

However, when I run `heroku open`
it does not work. The logs show that `Build Succeeded`
But it also says

```
2017-05-15T01:42:46.898625+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=clockgui-8872.herokuapp.com request_id=74b60a3e-a14a-4d6e-a90e-02d77a06e7fd fwd="64.134.102.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-15T01:42:47.255638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=clockgui-8872.herokuapp.com request_id=def81c28-c934-4757-8b6b-8206bad6b82e fwd="64.134.102.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Could anyone just let me know how to solve the problem to get the project run on heroku please?

***EDITED:***
The messages in the log before the H14 error is:

`2017-05-15T01:39:59.786432+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user modredlancelot@gmail.com
2017-05-15T01:40:00.078284+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user modredlancelot@gmail.com
2017-05-15T01:40:00.078284+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user modredlancelot@gmail.com
2017-05-15T01:40:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user modredlancelot@gmail.com
2017-05-15T01:40:44.609711+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 23f03d9 by user modredlancelot@gmail.com
2017-05-15T01:40:44.609711+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user modredlancelot@gmail.com
2017-05-15T01:40:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded`

And running "heroku ps" gives out:

`Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
ht tps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping`

=== web (Free): java -jar target/ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (1)
web.1: crashed 2017/05/15 21:29:47 -0400 (~ 1h ago)

I opened the directory with console the other day and just run
`heroku logs -t`

The error message changed to:

`2017-05-16T01:29:47.377793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-16T02:50:58.455898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=clockgui-8872.herokuapp.com request_id=e34d1d6d-4bf7-4758-9033-9db85edaf92e fwd="64.134.102.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-16T02:50:58.830851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=clockgui-8872.herokuapp.com request_id=a8e444b7-55ad-4fe1-a788-dacde8c223b4 fwd="64.134.102.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-16T07:22:09.411510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-16T07:22:12.136731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command java -jar target/ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-05-16T07:22:14.974069+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-05-16T07:22:14.980202+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-05-16T07:22:15.093579+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-05-16T07:22:15.188472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-16T07:22:15.200132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: Is there more output from `heroku logs` before the H14? What does `heroku ps` show?

Comment: Because the information added is too long to add here, I modify my question to give out the information you asked at the end.@codefinger

Comment: Try running `heroku logs -t` and leave it running. Then run `heroku ps:restart` in another terminal. Look for application specific error messages and post them here.

Comment: I actually have something like `no main manifest attribute, in target/ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` this time. I don't know what that means.

Comment: That means your JAR file is not executable and cannot be run with the -jar option. How do you run the app locally?

Comment: I use eclipse and it runs when I click the run button in the IDE.

Comment: What is your main class (the class that has the app's `main` method)?